# Avoid porn/nude recommendation in feed of android you tube app?

Tags: youtube

How can i avoid video containing porn/nude content from appearing up in feed/recommendation of my youtube app?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Youtube's settings, click General.
2. Enable "Restricted Mode".
3. Restart Youtube.

Comment: I tried it and somehow it show a reduction but not completely or dominantly

Comment: @engr Because it was showing before, I guess maybe there are still remnants of data from whatever used to be shown before. Close Youtube, its clear data and cache, start it and see if there is any difference.  However, you should also know that Restricted Mode is not 100% bulletproof.